# Error - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" in php while using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call external api in php using ajax-jquery.
But getting error 
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"

API doesn't support "JSONP". Any work around to make it work.

=============================
Code Snippet I tried.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://currency-api.appspot.com/api/CAD/EUR.json?key=b4a547e6aa86da2ced5278e3d21b4ad95e011ef8',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    async: true,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("---------SUCCESS-------------");               
        console.log(data);              
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("---------ERROR-------------");             
        console.log("** textStatus :" + textStatus);                
        console.log("** errorThrown :" + errorThrown);              
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("---------COMPLETE-------------");              
        console.log("** textStatus :" + textStatus);                
    }             
    });
}
```

=============================

I appreciate your prompt help.

Thanks,
SAV.

Comment: did you Google for the error string?  Did you search StackOverflow for it?  There are plenty of results which might help you.

Comment: I did search about it and tried below 1. added below in .htaccess file Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 2. added in php file header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'); But No luck. I am novice here. Thanks for being considerate. Plz help. Thanks, SAV

Answer (score 0):

sending isn't the problem, it's receiving, your browser won't let the AJAX call use the data because it came from another site. you need to add the header to the page, not the AJAX call.

Comment: I did search about it and tried below 
1. added below in .htaccess file
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

2. added in php file
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');

But No luck.

I am novice here. Thanks for being considerate.

Plz help.

Thanks,
SAV

Answer (score 0):

You will need a proxy hosted on the same domain as your script.
Then you'll request the distant API through it.

[A simple proxy in php](https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy).